# Synchronize cross-domain page address

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cross-browser, cross-domain, postmessage

I have two links:

```
http://something.something.com/ (an local institute server...)
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ (an amazon cloud C2)
```

I want my users and pretty much everyone to access `http://something.something.com/`, but this link is not mine to configure as I want, I only have FTP access to it and I want it to silently redirect the visitor to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/`.

I've researched and tested, using iframes, I don't get link translated, for instance, I don't get for example `http://something.something.com/something/` silently translated to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/something/`, on the iframe, it search for `something` in local server insted, and it did not exist. And navigating the iframe did not reflect on local host address

What I've read until now result in some ideas like using `postMessage` or `.htaccess`, but I'm confuse on what is the best (or even valid) solution for this as I'm not sure on even what I would search on google and would really be thankful for a guidance.

**update.1:**

I have limited access over FTP, it's a shared domain so I've got a `home/www/mydir` directory, I don't have access to server ROOT directory or system and services configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was trickier, but I've resolved it. To worsen things, my `local` address did not allow to use `.htaccess` proxy rules so I relied on `iframe` and `postMessage` and `.htaccess`.

After struggling on the lack of an proxy way, I've configured the `.htaccess` so any link resulted in the same address, my `index.html` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
```

On `local server`, the one users access, I did this:

```
    <iframe id="subD" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://x.x.x.x">
        Sorry your browser did not support iframes.
    </iframe>

    <script>
        // load url on iframe  
        var sub = window.location.pathname;
        document.getElementById("subD").
            contentWindow.document.
            location.href="http://x.x.x.x" + window.location.pathname;

        //get url from amazon server
        window.addEventListener("message", updateUrl, false);
        function updateUrl (event) {
            var origin = event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin;
            if (origin !== "http://x.x.x.x")
                return;
            current = window.location.pathname

            //take care of maintaining a back history whille navigating
            window.history.pushState({"link":current},"",event.data);
        }

        // on back/next event load history on frame
        window.onpopstate = function(e){
            if(e.state == e.state.link){
                var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
                var iframe = document.getElementById('subD');
                iframe.src = "http://x.x.x.x" + e.state.link + "?uid=" + rand;
            } else {
                history.back();
            }
        };
    </script>
```

On `amazon server` I send messages to update `local server`:

```
  <script>
      parent.postMessage(window.location.pathname,"http://something.something")
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

on local network, you can create alias by register the ip into `/etc/hosts` on each local pc.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   someting.something.com
```

Comment: I believe I was not precise, in fact I have limited access there are many pages stored in this institute and they have opened access over FTP, giving me a `home/www/myspace`

Comment: no, i mean if you apply it in your local pc, 
you can access to `http://something.something.com/something` from your local browser. but in fact your request will be sent to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/something`, no server configuration changes

Comment: Oh, interesting, but I need this to work to anyone accessing it from anywhere. But I undestand, the question is ambiguous :)

Comment: if you want to access from anywhere (another pc), the flow is similar, but you need to register that ip in your dns at your network.

Comment: This is the problem, I dont have a "DNS domain to set", I have a space in a server: `http://something.something.com/` that I want to in fact access an external server `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/` "silently" (still using http://something.something.com/ address)

Comment: I've updated the question, trying to make it more clear